# How to get code coverage results of multiple files through a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bazel, coverage.py

I am having troubles using the coverage.py module in my python script. The scenario is:

I have a script which calls upon test scripts and executes them as this was the only way to call multiple tests within my environment that works. I would like to get coverage reports generated for each of these tests that are called upon and executed within my script. For example:

```
Cov = coverage.Coverage()
Cov.start()
Subprocess.call("bazel run :test", shell=true) #or "bazel test ..."
Cov.stop()
Cov.html_report(directory=my/directory, include=test/name)
```

However, as you probably know, this implementation does not work and returns "no data to report". How can I get it so that I can start and stop coverage for each test? Or is this approach even possible?

If any of this is unclear, I can try to explain something better.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: `coverage` operates within the Python process.  You just have to use it inside the subprocess somehow.

Comment: Yes I originally had the same idea, however the bazel build environment prevents me from doing that directly without explicitly stating coverage.py as a direct dependency of each file I am trying to get coverage on.